# SharePoint Online site custom theme

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-site

I am trying to make a custom theme for SharePoint online site. I want a colorful navigation dropdown. Is it possible to use the script for this purpose? Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Fluent UI Theme Designer you can design and export it.

Use the below Custom Theme designer tools.

[Fluent UI Theme Designer](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html)

For more information refer the below Microsoft Docs.

[SharePoint Online site theming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)